# Docker disk space leak

Tags: docker, docker-compose

After several runs of `docker-compose build` commands I am starting to get "nospc and is related to insufficient space on your system". I don't have any dangling images or volumes. What could be reason for this? 
The only thing which helps is removing docker folder on host machine, restarting it and recreating all the images from scratch. What could be causing this?
Operating system Ubuntu 14.0, Docker version 1.12.1.

Comment: "I don't have any dangling images or volumes" — What about exited containers?  Have you been cleaning them up as well?

Comment: you're not using docker for mac, right? that has known issues in this area.

Comment: please provide information about the operating system and docker version

Comment: There's a huge disk leak in docker for windows. There are folders under windowsfilter ending in "-removing" that are left behind. Even after deleting all containers and pruning all images, these folders remain. Docker leaves them behind, seems totally oblivious to them, and it does not clean them up when you restart the service. Just hundreds of gigabytes of space. We see this problem in AWS, and because its task placement algorithm does not take disk space into account, it keeps trying to place tasks on these full boxes that leave stuff behind every time a task is removed. It's unusable.